# Can TypeScript output javadoc comments?

Tags: javadoc, google-closure-compiler, typescript

Since TypeScript doesn't support minification or obfuscation, both of which are features we need, we still need a tool like Google's Closure compiler in our tool chain. Is there anyway to get TypeScript to output javadoc comments automatically, so that Closure can just become an automated step?

Without it, it looks like these tools are largely incompatible, because we need to have javadoc comments, which means we can't use TypeScript. It seems like it would be an easy feature to add, since you know the types of everything.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 2):

The TypeScript does not produce documentation or extra comments; you can however preserve comments (jsDoc or any other format) in TypeScript files to the emitted JavaScript passing the -c or (--comments) to the compiler.

Comment: That's insufficient, though, right? Because the TypeScript compiler creates your source code, it would need to put the jsDoc comments in when the variables are first used. In Anders' demo where the live js was getting created, first references are created in very different places in the js than in the ts.

Comment: @BlackSnapper Correct. With -c it will not strip the comments you author but it doesn't emit JsDoc comments itself. This would make a great suggestion on CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Micheal Bolin posted how he cracked it: [Generating Google Closure JavaScript from TypeScript](http://blog.bolinfest.com/2013/01/generating-google-closure-javascript.html).

Since IntellJ IDEA now understand (though not fully) Closure Jsdoc, TypeScript is not necessary now for IDE.